# Filter out items in object with duplicate Key A by highest value of Key B

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Sorry in advance if this is a simple question. I know that filtering objects & arrays has been covered from every angle, just struggling to understand how to implement it in this case.

I have an object of items from a JSON, each offered by multiple providers in varying qualities (as well as a load of other info I’ve not included below).

I'm trying to filter this original object to return a new object containing only the best offering quality for each offering provider ID, (as well as the rest of the info for that entry).

The qualities are all known string values, contained in an array by descending order of preference.

So I have:

```
const qualities = ["great", "good", "bad", "awful"];

const offerings = 
[{item_id: 1,
offering_provider_id: 1,
offering_quality: "good",
link: "abc.xyz"},
{item_id: 1,
offering_provider_id: 1,
offering_quality: "great",
link: "abc.xyz"},
{item_id: 1,
offering_provider_id: 2,
offering_quality: "bad",
link: "xyz.abc"}]
```

And I want to return:

```
const filteredOfferings = 
[{item_id: 1,
offering_provider_id: 1,
offering_quality: "great",
link: "abc.xyz"},
{item_id: 1,
offering_provider_id: 2,
offering_quality: "bad",
link: "xyz.abc"}]
```

And filter out duplicate offerings from the same provider with lower qualities.

I felt like it must be v. simple - using either a helper array and for loops, or lodash or something.

I tried to put it through a for loop, adding each new provider as they came up, and only updating it the next time if it's a higher offering, but my javascript isn’t strong, and for some reason I just can’t get my head around it!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Alex

EDIT:
as barmar suggested, I took another look at my code and am adding it here.
I think I've made it work - but it seems a bit slow and *very* clunky, so help would still be greatly appreciated!

```
    const filteredOffersArray = [];

    const providerHighestOffering = [];

    for(var i= 0, l = offerings.length; i< l; i++){
        if ( providerHighestOffering.some(item => item.offering_provider_id_and_type === offerings[i].offering_provider_id+offerings[i].offering_provider_type) ) 
        {  
            var currentOfferingQuality = providerHighestOffering.find(item => item.offering_provider_id_and_type === offerings[i].offering_provider_id+offerings[i].offering_provider_type).offering_quality;
            var newOfferingQuality = offerings[i].offering_quality;
            if ( qualities.indexOf(newOfferingQuality) < qualities.indexOf(currentOfferingQuality) ) {
                var currentHighestOfferingIndex = providerHighestOffering.findIndex(item => item.offering_provider_id_and_type===offerings[i].offering_provider_id+offerings[i].offering_provider_type);
                providerHighestOffering.splice(currentHighestOfferingIndex, 1);
                providerHighestOffering.push( { original_array_position: i, offering_provider_id_and_type: offerings[i].offering_provider_id+offerings[i].offering_provider_type, offering_provider_id : offerings[i].offering_provider_id, offering_provider_type : offerings[i].offering_provider_type, offering_quality : offerings[i].offering_quality } );
            }
        } else { 
            providerHighestOffering.push( { original_array_position: i, offering_provider_id_and_type: offerings[i].offering_provider_id+offerings[i].offering_provider_type, offering_provider_id : offerings[i].offering_provider_id, offering_provider_type : offerings[i].offering_provider_type, offering_quality : offerings[i].offering_quality } );
        }
    }

    for(var i= 0, l = offerings.length; i< l; i++){
        if(providerHighestOffering.some(item => item.original_array_position === i)) {
            filteredOffersArray.push(offerings[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(filteredOffersArray);
```

Comment: Show what you tried, and we'll help you fix it. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: The method you mentioned should work. You should use an object whose key is the provider ID to hold the current highest item for each provider.

Comment: thank you for suggesting that @Barmar - updated above. I also took another look at it and think I have got it doing something, but very clunkily. would still appreciate any thoughts on how to optimise it.

Comment: You should use an object whose key is the provider ID, not an array that you have to search every time to find a matching provider ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and store the objects with the highest quality.

```js
const
    qualities = ["great", "good", "bad", "awful"],
    getQuality = q => qualities.length - qualities.indexOf(q),
    offerings = [{ item_id: 1, offering_provider_id: 1, offering_quality: "good", link: "abc.xyz" }, { item_id: 1, offering_provider_id: 1, offering_quality: "great", link: "abc.xyz" }, { item_id: 1, offering_provider_id: 2, offering_quality: "bad", link: "xyz.abc" }],
    filtered = Array.from(offerings
        .reduce(
            (m, o) => (item => m.set(o.item_id, item && getQuality(item.offering_quality) > getQuality(o.offering_quality) ? item : o))
                (m.get(o.item_id)),
            new Map
        )
        .values()
    );

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching an array for the provider ID every time is very inefficient, you should use an object whose key is the provider ID.

Also, make the qualities into an object that maps the keywords to values (or just store numbers in the objects, and translate it to a word when displaying).

```js
const qualities = {
  "great": 4,
  "good": 3,
  "bad": 2,
  "awful": 1
};
const offerings = [{
    item_id: 1,
    offering_provider_id: 1,
    offering_quality: "good",
    link: "abc.xyz"
  },
  {
    item_id: 1,
    offering_provider_id: 1,
    offering_quality: "great",
    link: "abc.xyz"
  },
  {
    item_id: 1,
    offering_provider_id: 2,
    offering_quality: "bad",
    link: "xyz.abc"
  }
];

const by_provider = {};

offerings.forEach(o => {
  if (!by_provider[o.offering_provider_id] || qualities[by_provider[o.offering_provider_id].offering_quality] < qualities[o.offering_quality]) {
    by_provider[o.offering_provider_id] = o;
  }
});

const filtered_offerings = Object.values(by_provider);
console.log(filtered_offerings);
```